# How to restart git bash in Windows

Tags: windows, git-bash

I update the PATH variable in Windows but it doesn't affect git bash. the PATH update only after restarting the computer. I want to restart the git bash without restarting the whole computer.

Comment: wait, does closing git bash and reopening it doesn't make it reload the path?

Comment: yep, restarting the git bash itself should do the trick unless its still running in the background or invoked from context menu (right click) - see [previous QA](https://superuser.com/questions/671005/git-for-windows-how-to-apply-changes-in-path-without-reboot).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was opening git bash via vs code. thanks @BagusTesa. You can move your comment to answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.